# search a file for a string

Tags: c, file, search

I have to search the file for a string entered but the code below doesn't work. It always says "couldn't find in the dictionary. The contents of the file (called `Dictionary.txt`) is as follows:

```
pow
jaw
pa$$word
```

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 30

main()
{
    char inPassword[MAX + 1];
    printf("\nEnter a password: ");
    gets(inPassword);

    printf("\n\nYou entered: %s, please wait, checking in dictionary.\n\n",inPassword);
    checkWordInFile("Dictionary.txt",inPassword);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("pause");
}//end of main


void checkWordInFile(char *fileName, char *password);
{
    char readString[MAX + 1];
    FILE *fPtr;
    int iFound = -1;
    //open the file
    fPtr = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (fPtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNo dictionary file\n");
        printf("\n\n\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(0);    // just exit the program
    }


    while(fgets(readString, MAX, fPtr))
    {
            if(strcmp(password, readString) == 0)
        {
            iFound = 1;
        }

    }

    fclose(fPtr);

    if( iFound > 0 )
    {
        printf("\nFound your word in the dictionary");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nCould not find your word in the dictionary");
    }


}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use boolean values for `iFound`?

Comment: Maybe he's coding in ANSI C rather than C99.

Comment: Shouldn't you main be int main( void )?

Comment: Just in case you are interested in optimizations: for large number of searches will be faster to pre-sort dictionary and use binary search (O(log(n))) or if memory is not a problem you can hash all strings and preform search in (O(1), for small hash load factors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fgets() leaves the \n on the end of the string unless EOF. This fixes it:

```
while(fgets(readString, MAX, fPtr))
{
    size_t ln = strlen(readString);
    if (ln && readString[ln-1] == '\n') { readString[ln-1] = 0; --ln; }
    if(ln && strcmp(password, readString) == 0)
    {
        iFound = 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

how would I change this function to search for a substring that this file contains ? eg If I enter a word "repow234" I should get a message that this is incorrect beacuse "pow" is the file and cannot be used

this doesn't work:

```
while(fgets(readString, MAX, fPtr))
{
    if (strstr( password, readString) != NULL)
    {
        iFound = 1;
    }
}

fclose(fPtr);

if( iFound > 0 )
{
    printf("\nThis password cannot be used because it contains the word in the dictionary");
}
else
{
    printf("\nThis password can be used");
}
```